# How to add a beanstalk app to a security group as a inbound rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

I have two Elastic Beanstalk applications "a" and "b". Anyone should be able to talk to (a) over http, but only (a) should be able to talk to (b). I.e.

internet -> a -> b

Right now, everything works if both apps are fully open to the internet. But as soon as I try to restrict the security group for (b)'s ELB, (a) can't seem to connect anymore.

I.e. If I allow (b)'s load balancer security group to allow http:0.0.0.0/0, everything works. But if I set that same security group to allow only http:[(a)'s security group], (a) can no longer communicate with (b).

Both apps are in the same VPC. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your second environment has an external load balancer. That means the traffic from environment A to environment B will exit the VPC and come back in, at which point the association with environment A's security group is lost.

You need to convert environment B to use an internal load balancer. [The Elastic Beanstalk setting for that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html) is:

Namespace: `aws:ec2:vpc`

Name: `ELBScheme`

Value: `internal`